# How to retrieve values using Ksoap2 webservice

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I would like to retrieve array of values from java webservice in android. I am using ksoap 3.0 jar with dependencies.

I want to retrieve array of values as follows:

Array ( [resultStatus] => true [responseObjSize] => 12 [responseObjects] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 ) ) [2] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 0 ) ) [3] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 0 ) ) [4] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 0 ) ) [5] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 0 ) ) [6] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 0 ) ) [7] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 0 ) ) [8] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 0 ) ) [9] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 0 ) ) [10] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 0 ) ) [11] => Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 0 ) ) ) )

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: I retrieved values like below code but couldn't retrieve it properly

Comment: As far as I know, SOAP relies on XML information set and the structure which you have shown above looks like JSON structure. Can you share part of your XML response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";**

```
 public static String GetColor(Context c) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        String METHOD_NAME = "GetColor";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/youruri name/";

        SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                METHOD_NAME);
        // Use this to add parameters

        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
        return WebCalls.call(c, request, .NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME,
                SOAP_ACTION);
    } 






public static String call(Context c, SoapObject request, String NAMESPACE,
                String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION) throws IOException,
                XmlPullParserException {
            Log.i(WebCalls, "URL " + your URL);
            Log.i(WebCalls, "Method Name " + METHOD_NAME);
            Log.i(WebCalls, "request Name " + request);
            String SoapResult = null;
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            envelope.dotNet = true;

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    CommonVariable.URL);

            // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                SoapResult = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
            } else {
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                SoapResult = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
            }

            Log.i(WebCalls, "Response " + SoapResult);

            return SoapResult;
        }
```

i hope this is useful method too you...if any query then tell me..this code have implemented in my current project.now its working fine.

Comment: hey dipali I am facing issue in ksoap2. It is giving response as Authentication Fail

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The dipali's code helps you to consume the webService.
Once you have the SoapResult, you have to unmarshall it in order to fetch all of the response element.

If your Soap response is only an array of integer, here an example:

```
SoapObject obj =(SoapObject) resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0);

for(int i=0; i<obj.getPropertyCount(); i++)
{
   int id= Integer.parseInt(obj.getProperty(i).toString());
   //Do what you want
}
```